# Laravel Form::select not binding on model in production, but local

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, laravelcollective

I am running a Laravel app on heroku and built a multi step form, that updates the object on every step. I also make use of the HTML library, which assists me in creating the forms, see my code below. Now I realized, that the model binding for selects is not working, when I open the form later. Instead, the first option of the array of options is displayed as default.
However, this only happens on production environment (heroku) and not on my local xampp server. Furthermore, model binding works in production on numbers or strings, only selects don't bind correctly.
I also tested, that the object has the correct value so it's not a database saving error and everything works fine.

Review my code below:

```
// Form is opened here
{!! Form::model($umzug, ['method'=>'PUT', 'action' => array('UmzugController@update', $umzug->id)]) !!}
...
<div class="col-sm-6">
  {!! Form::label('halteverbot_auszug', 'Halteverbot') !!}
  // Following line prints 'N', as it was selected previously and was therefore saved correctly in the DB
  {{ $umzug->halteverbot_auszug }}
  // Following line should produce a select input with 'Nein' selected, but shown 'Ja' instead 
  {!! Form::select('halteverbot_auszug', ['J' => 'Ja', 'N' => 'Nein'], null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'id'=>'halteverbot_auszug'])  !!}
</div>
...
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

As the code is the same in production and on local, I have no clue how it can produce different outcomes, but I would be glad to hear any suggestions on how I can fix it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you added laravel collective to your production server? may be you should check your composer.json file in production and update composer in your production.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution did not resolve my problem.

Comment: What you tried and what you got, any error message?

Comment: I ran heroku run composer update, everything was updated to the latest version (as in local production) successfully, but the original problem was not resolved with this step. I can provide additional information, if you tell me what you need.

Comment: Have you checked your composer.json file in your production?

Comment: Yes. The following line ist listed in the "require", as it is in local mode: "laravelcollective/html": "^5.4",

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182890/discussion-between-rufrage-and-prafulla-kumar-sahu).

Comment: I want to know if that line exists in your production composer.json?

Comment: Yes it does exist

Comment: I would suggest you to create an issue in github, if you are not getting any error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue, by using 0 and 1 instead of 'J' and 'N'. I assume, that the different database types (mysql locally and postgresql on heroku) are handling characters different and second not as well as the first. Using integers instead fixed my problem.